# Angular 6+ Cache issue

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx, angular6, angular7

In the back end server we have changed the HTTP method from POST to GET and some other request method as well. like PUT to POST.
But browser is still calling the old HTTP method which is old version of the application.
It might be due to cache. But unable to solve this issue with

`ng build -prod --output-hashing=none`

Users still facing the same issue till the cache in the browser is cleared.
We are using nginx as middle layer.

Comment: you changed it on the backend you say, it has nothing to do with the browser

Comment: Why don't you enable output hashing?

Comment: But browser is caching the old js files and calling the same old Http Method @DPro

Comment: Yeah it is already enable but still we see the error? @David

Comment: output-hashing=none disables the hashing

Answer (score 0):

You try ng build -prod --output-hashing=all

More info: https://angular.io/cli/build